# Find percentage in R filtering for different conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, percentage

I am trying to collect some summary statistics about data from the National Health Interview Survey comparing migrant and US born workers. For example, I'd like to be able to calculate what percent of workers have did not complete high school, completed high school, college degree, and so on. I think I could use codes that come with dplyr but I am unsure of the simplest way to do this! Here's what my codes look like:

NHIS1=data frame, IMMIGRANT=binary indicator (1=immigrant, 0=US born), NEWEDUC= education variable (1=grade 12 or less (no high school grad), 2= high school grad/GED, 3= some college no degree, 4= associate's degree , 5=bachelors and beyond)

For example, I'd like to know: 
How could I calculate the percent of all workers who didn't graduate high school 
How could I calculate the percent of only US born workers who got a college degree?

I tried something like this...

`NHIS1 %>% 
  group_by(NEWEDUC) %>% 
    sum(percent= 100*n()NEWEDUC == "1") / n())`

or for just the immigrant group, doing something like this: 
 `NHIS_test=subset(NHIS1, NEWEDUC==1 & IMMIGRANT==1) 
  nrow(NHIS_test)/nrow(NHIS1$IMMIGRANT==1)`

Thank you!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with expected otuput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are asking for, but in general in base R you can do something like this to get the summary percentages of data after filtering it:

```
filters1 = NHIS1$NEWEDUC == 1  # didn't graduate high school
sum(filters1) * 100 / nrow(NHIS1)

filters2 = NHIS1$IMMIGRANT == 0 # US born
filters3 = NHIS1$IMMIGRANT == 0 & NHIS1$NEWEDUC %in% c(4, 5) # US born with college degree
sum(filters3) * 100 / sum(filters2)
```